# RestSharp.RestClient.ExecuteTaskAsync Waiting Forever

Tags: c#, restsharp

I tried to look for a solution from RestSharp docs, examples, and stack overflow posts but found nothing that is applicable to my situation.

What I'm trying to do here is to send multiple async requests at the same time, and waiting for all of them to come back with their response before proceeding - consuming data at the same time.  However, the program hangs on Task.WaitAll.

```
    public List<CatalogModel> GetCatalogListAsync(string url, List<string> handles)
    {
        tasks = new List<Task<IRestResponse<CatalogModel>>>();
        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            var task = GetCatalogTaskAsync(url, handle);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        var tasksArray = tasks.ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasksArray);

        var catalogList = new List<CatalogModel>();
        foreach (var task in tasksArray)
        {
            var result = task.Result;
            var catalog = new CatalogModel();
            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                catalog = result.Data;
            }
            else
            {
                _logging.LogErrorMessage(result.ErrorMessage);
            }
            catalogList.Add(catalog);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here's the method that's in charge of returning tasks.

```
public async Task<IRestResponse<CatalogModel>> GetCatalogTaskAsync(string url, string handle)
    {
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest(){Resource = $"catalog/{handle}.json"};

        return await client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync<CatalogModel>(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Task is being returned and never gets activated.  So Task.WaitAll is just waiting for something to happen.

To fix this, I have to add a callback method when Client.ExecuteAsync is called.

```
    public Task<IRestResponse> GetCatalogAsync(string url, string handle)
    {
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest(){Resource = $"catalog/{handle}.json"};
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(response);
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Then by using Task.WaitAll in the calling method, the code will just run successfully.